# running console application from nodejs app using child_process

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm trying to run instances of console application ( written on cpp ) from nodejs by using child_process . 
Here is the code :

```
function startSingleApp() {
    console.log("startSingleApp entered");

    var exec = childProcess.exec;
    var appOut;
    exec("./ConsoleApplication.exe"  ,function callback(error, stdout, stderr){
        appOut = stdOut;
        console.log("started console app");
    });
};
```

And ConsoleApplication4 only prints strings ( cout<<"some string")
Expected behavior : for each instance of ConsoleApplication4 - console window opened and new process created
Actual behavior : no console window , no process create . But "started console app" string printed on console ( from which nodejs app started ) 
ConsoleApplication.exe located in same folder where nodejs app located
If replace ConsoleApplication.exe by some window app ( notepad or calc) - it works.
The question - what is missing in this code ? Do I need manually catch console out from the consoleapplication ?
Your help will be helpful.
Thaks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run a console application from a console, it’s still going to run in the same console. The Windows console is just a convenience that opens automatically when you’re running a console application through Explorer.

You can try it yourself: open `cmd.exe` first, then run `ConsoleApplication.exe`. It won’t open a new window; the output will appear beneath your prompt. And then you’ll get another one.

If you want a window to show up, you can run `cmd` manually:

```
exec("cmd /c ConsoleApplication.exe", function callback(error, stdout, stderr) {
    appOut = stdOut;
    console.log("started console app");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply - but it still does not work

Comment: How doesn’t it work? Do you really need the window? And have you checked the `error` argument the callback was passed?

Comment: Some update : currently it prints logs into same console as nodejs. I removed waiting for key input at the end of the console app.Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `start` to make a new console window like this:

```
exec("start ConsoleApplication.exe", ....)
```

and add a line in your C++:

```
getch();
```

Comment: If you add something like getch() or cin>>keyToRead it does not work. After removing it - you can see console output. Anyway thanks for reply